# How to stop recording voice automatically in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, recording

I use this system https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs for recording voice and then download it to PC. When I want to record voice I have to hit start button, and when I want to stop it, I have to hit stop.

**Problem**

I want to do it automatically, so when I hit start  button it will start recording voice and when I stop talking it will stop recording automatically.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any easy way to do it in this code. I would really appreciate, because I am new in JS and PHP and I don't know how to do it.
2. Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: I improved the format of the question for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recognizing the voice content is not a simple job and can not be done using pure  javascript. Obviously A third party software on server (e.g. Matlab) is needed which has direct access to the file content and a series of mathematical analyze is needed to recognize if the voice is stopped or is low (after omitting noises!)

There are some limited solutions like [this](https://dictation.io/) which use third party servers and you may implement them using javascript to record voice or convert speech to text. How ever these solutions are not yet **web service** and you can not make programming on their actions and abilities.